# How to make the css asset follow a certain order in symfony2 projetcs

Tags: css, symfony, assets, assetic

Today I deployed my application and I experienced a problem regarding my css.

In my main template I have the following code :

```
<!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
{% stylesheets
     'bundles/appgenerictheme/current/frontend/css/style1.css'
     'bundles/appgenerictheme/current/frontend/css/style2.css'
     'bundles/appgenerictheme/current/frontend/css/style3.css'

     output='css/style.css' filter='cssrewrite'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

The order bellow 1,2,3 is important because in style2.css I overide some rules defined in style1.css etc ...

In my dev environment I had no problems because the css are rendered like this :

```
<!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app_dev.php/css/style1.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app_dev.php/css/style2.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app_dev.php/css/style3.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
```

But in production environment, the rules changes and the assets are concatenated in one single file : style.css

```
<!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
```

If I look into the generated style.css I can see that the order is not style1 -> style2 -> style3 but some random order making my rules to override css useless.

Is there a way to explicitly define an order for the concatenation of style.css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to replicate this issue to no avail. It does respect the order in which I define them in my case.

Make sure you:

1. Install your assets: `php app/console assets:install web`
2. Dump the new **CSS** file: `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`
3. Clear the cache: `rm -fr app/cache/*`

in that specific order.

Anyway, if that doesn't help you could try using different directories, like this:

```
<!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
{% stylesheets
     'bundles/appgenerictheme/current/frontend/css/style1.css'
     'bundles/appgenerictheme/current/frontend/css/d1/style2.css'
     'bundles/appgenerictheme/current/frontend/css/d1/d2/style3.css'

     output='css/style.css' filter='cssrewrite'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: I was using capifony to deploy and automate those task for me but with more configuration, it appear to be on the right order (at least my overriding works). I made a lot of modification on the deploy.rb from capifony, so I can't tell which one solved the issue, but thank you for your answer, I'll keep it for future references.